# Transforming SELECT query into UPDATE with DISTINCT result. Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have this query here and I would need to convert it to an update statement.

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(Domain, LEN(Domain) - CHARINDEX('@', Domain)) AS email_domain
FROM dbo.DomainsV7
WHERE Domain IS NOT NULL;
```

> *I have a table with some data one of them are Emails that are stored in column called "Domain".*
>
> *I would need to update "Domain" so I cut the emails and only leave domains (Example: test@testmail.com that would after query be like
>   this testmail.com). So the Domain column has over 290000 emails stored
>   inside and there are also some NULL's...*
>
> *As I said I am looking for domains and I don't need data left of and including @ Also don't need duplicated domain list or NULL values in
>   Domain column. So what I am looking for is a query that will trim the
>   emails to transform them into domains at the same time the query would
>   remove the data with NULL value and duplicated domains.*
>
> *The final result should be column Domain with only unique domains and without NULLs inside.*

Table name: dbo.DomainsV7

Table structure:

```
COLUMN NAME     |      DATA TYPE      |    ALLOW NULLS
----------------+---------------------+-----------------
   Domain       |     Varchar(60)     |        YES
```

^ Made a mistake allowing NULL data in the first place.

Here is how the table looks now:

```
    +-------------------------+
    |         Domain          |
    +-------------------------+
    | example@fakemail.com    |
    | example2@randommail.com |
    | example3@fakemail.com   |  <- Will be removed after update (Duplicate)
    |          ...            |
    +-------------------------+
```

Here is how I need the table to look after the UPDATE:

```
+-------------------------+
|         Domain          |
+-------------------------+
|     fakemail.com        |
|    randommail.com       |
|          ...            |
+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 stages for 3 tasks:

First, we update the domains to include only the domain

```
update d1
set domain = RIGHT(Domain, LEN(Domain) - CHARINDEX('@', Domain))
from DomainsV7 d1
where d1.domain is not null
and CHARINDEX('@', d1.Domain) > 0 -- in case there is a value with no '@';
```

Next, we adios the blank ones

```
delete from domainsv7
where domain is null;
```

Finally, we delete the duplicates

```
with CTE as
(
select domain, row_number() over(partition by domain order by domain) rn
from domainsv7
)
delete from CTE
where rn >1;
```

Comment: i was thinking about cursors but i know its gonna be slow but i didnt get your answer could you please eaborate your answer

Comment: Everything runs smooth until the 3rd step. I get this error message: "Msg 5308, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Windowed functions and NEXT VALUE FOR functions do not support integer indices as ORDER BY clause expressions."

Comment: You can't have `order by 1`, replace with `order by domain`

Comment: Works like a charm. MARKING this answer as the correct answer as it was the fastest one to be placed here. Thank you all for contributing!

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create a new table with the domains you want and then re-insert them:

```
SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(Domain, LEN(Domain) - CHARINDEX('@', Domain)) AS email_domain
INTO #domains
FROM dbo.DomainsV7
WHERE Domain IS NOT NULL;

TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.DomainsV7;

INSERT INTO dbo.DomainsV7 (domain)
    SELECT email_domain
    FROM #domains;
```